# How do I set encoding to be UTF8 when I serialize a file in JAVA(Eclipse)

Tags: java, file, serialization, encoding, binary

I tried to write to a file in Java by serialization ("for example object.out") but it can't be read normally. Instead it is showing me something like this ��

I tried setting preferences encoding to UTF-8

```
public void serijalizujufajl() {
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("osobe.out");

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)){
        for (int j = 0; j <osobe.size(); j++) {
            oos.writeObject(osobe.get(j));

        }oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot or Eclipse]

Comment: It can't be read "normally" because it isn't a text file, it's a binary file.

Comment: Ok, so it's supposed to look like this?

Comment: I'm an absolute begginer, so forgive me in advance :|

Comment: As a beginner, be aware that except for (apparent) class assignments like this, new real-world code has mostly moved to using JSON, XML, or other compatible serialization mechanisms instead of Java serialization.

Comment: Thank you! This is just part of a small practice for school subject, I'm not coding it for myself

Comment: As a small note, you don't need to call `oos.close()`. Since you declared `oos` from in the `try (...)` part, the Java compiler will automatically call `close` on it for you. (That only works because you declared it within the try's parenthesis section. If you'd declared it within the `{...}` part, the compiler wouldn't add the `close`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectOutputStream` is not intended for human consumption. The only thing to do with data written with `ObjectOutputStream` is to read it back in with `ObjectInputStream`. There are many other technologies in Java to write data for humans to read or for interchange with other systems. The object stream format already uses Unicode as part of its representation, you don't need to configure it.